# Update object when using entity splitting - code first

Tags: entity-framework

I had a class called Document, which I split into two entities, in order to separate an expensive binary field:

```
[Table("Document")]
public class Document
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ... other fields ...

    [Required]
    public virtual DocumentBinary DocumentBinary { get; set; }
}

[Table("Document")]
public class DocumentBinary
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Document")]
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }

    public Document Document { get; set; }

    public byte[] DocumentData { get; set; }
}
```

So, everything works fine, both entities share the same database table and DocumentData is only loaded when it's needed.

However, when it comes to updating the Document entity, I get an error stating that *'DocumentBinary is required'*.

When I remove the *[Required]* attribute from DocumentBinary virtual property, I get the following error:

*The entity types 'Document' and 'DocumentBinary' cannot share table 'Documents' because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them.*

I can obviously do something like:

```
var test = document.DocumentBinary;
```

before updating the document object:

```
documentRepository.Update(document);
```

This will then load the binary data on my request and save the changes without any issues, but the whole point is that I shouldn't need to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve it by overriding my Update method in DocumentRepository:

```
public override void Update(Document document)
{
    try
    {
        DataContext.Entry(document.DocumentBinary).State = EntityState.Modified; // added this line
        DataContext.Entry(document).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    catch (System.Exception exception)
    {
        throw new EntityException("Failed to update document");
    }
}
```

I know it probably does the same thing as me evaluating DocumentBinary by assigning it to 'test' variable, but it looks like a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using the fluent API. If you remove the data annotations and in your `OnModelCreating` add this, it should work.

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
     modelBuilder.Entity<Document>().HasRequired(d => d.DocumentBinary).
                                     WithRequiredDependent(db => db.Document);

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It will probably work (tried before, but with the wrong order!), but I prefer to use data annotations as I find them more descriptive. 

I just managed to find a solution myself, which I will post in a moment.